# Simple tensorflow example :

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So i am trying to make a micro example of how to use tensorflow :

Here are my data :

```
train_images = numpy.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[1,2,2],[2,1,3],[3,21]])
```

The main goal is to find that the first number of each array is equal to the label.

Here is my code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy


model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(3, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

class_names = ['chiffre 1',' chiffre 2',' chiffre 3']

train_images = numpy.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[1,2,2],[2,1,3],[3,21]])

train_labels = numpy.array(['1','2','3','1','2','3'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

test_images =numpy.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[1,2,2]])

test_labels = numpy.array(['1','2','3','1'])

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

test_image =numpy.array([[1,1,1]])
predictions = model.predict(test_image)

pred = numpy.argmax(predictions[0])
print(pred)
print(class_names[pred])
print(predictions)

#print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
```

I know that this line is false :

```
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(3, 3)),
```

but how to make it correct ?
Regards

Answer (score 3):

Start with deleting your Flatten layer, your data points are 1d vectors, flattening 1d vectors is meaningless.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu , input_shape=(3,)),
keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
```

first dense layer takes three inputs, this is the size of your each data point.

Since there are three classes, we need to change the output shape of the second layer too.

```
train_labels = numpy.array([0,1,2,0,1,2])
test_labels = numpy.array([0,1,2,0])
```

sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss function expects train and test labels to be in range of [0, 3). so we map 1 to 0 , 2 to 1 and 3 to 2.

model, runs and learns with these changes, I suggest Increasing epoch number since you have very limited data.

Comment: i still have an error :  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable for the line 7  : keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu , input_shape=3),

Comment: input_shape=(3,)